# What is the purpose of 'end' event in https requests in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, httprequest

I started learning programming couple months ago and learning Node.js recently. I have a question about the http.get() method. I have read the documentation and search for explanations but couldn't find anything. On http.get() method, when we add a listener for ‘data’ event, we only assign received data to a variable. And then parse the data in another listener to ‘end’ event. Such as this:

```
http.get('http://nodejs.org/dist/index.json', (res) => {
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { 
    rawData += chunk; 
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
    console.log(parsedData);
  });
};
```

However, I can also parse the data in the ‘data’ event listener, and it works too.

```
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { 
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(chunk);
    console.log(parsedData);
  });
```

**What is the reason that we need to add another listener to ‘end’ event in order to parse the data ?**

My assumption is, it works because the data I requested is quite small, but if it was a big amount of data it would take some time and node would move on to process the next line of code, like asynchronous codes. Or I only made one requests, but in case there are multiple requests we need to wait for ‘data’ event to finish and deal with it in the ‘end’ listener. But in such case, I assume, I would like to separate every response in another variable.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback if in doubt, check the docs :)

Comment: "*My assumption is, it works because the data I requested is quite small*" precisely, you keep receiving data in *chunks*, and you have no guarantees those chunks will fit into a single `data` event. When there is no data anymore for sure, the `end` event is dispatched, so if you want to write a reliable software, you better use `end` instead.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi, okay that answers to my question, thanks for the explanation.